# MongoDB Sort by value in embedded document array using reactiveMongoTemplate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, reactive-mongo-java

I have MongoDB Collection of documents as below format.

`

```
{
    "_id" : "...",
    "parameters" : [     
            {
            "name" : "ApplicationId",
            "value" :" App1"
            },
            {
            "name" : "policyId",
            "value" :" pol1"
            },
            {
            "name" : "primaryCustomerId",
            "value" :" cust1"
            },
            {
            "name" : "brokerId",
            "value" :" broker1"
            },
            ...
     ],
    "createDateTime": "2020-01-14T18:32:19Z",
    "updateDateTime": "2020-10-05T00:54:17Z",
    "createdBy": "54420583-5ece-4261-a616-12f8c27e220d",
    "updatedBy": "54420583-5ece-4261-a616-12f8c27e220d",
    ...
 }
```

How can I write a query to find collections which will do search using "parameters" is having element name = brokerId and value = broker1 and it will sort on value of element(parameters.value) using parameters.name =primaryCustomerId using reactiveMongoTemplate?

I am trying aggregation and projection for the same. But somehow I am unable to add field(which we can user later for sorting) in aggregation using reactiveMongoTemplate.